# Sci-fi novel about some teens travelling back to the time of Galileo

Tags: story-identification, books, time-travel

I'm looking for a sci-fi novel I read years ago, probably between 2007-2013

I think there was a 3D-like illustration of Galileo on the front cover and the novel was part of a series.

Some teens travel back in time in a train where they have some sort of an AI assistant called ALEC (I am not too sure of the name). They went to Pisa to witness Galileo performing an experiment of how objects of different masses fall at the same rate towards the Earth.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published?

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/28327460-fractured-horizons includes time travel and Galileo, but no train, and only two teenagers.

Comment: @LogicDictates I don't really remember. I am guessing within 2007-2013.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add. For example, what were the character's names? How did the train help them travel in time? Did they travel willingly? Were they male or female teens? Where were they going on the train? Were they young teens or older? What was the setting that they had an AI assistant? How did they get back (if they got back)? What language was the book written in? Did they speak Italian or use some kind of translator?